# Вызов запроса на получение прав администратора в нужное время

Tags: winapi

Знаю, что задать требование прав администратора можно в манифесте приложения, но это требование будет работать с самого начала запуска программы. А как вызвать подтверждение администратора в определённом участке кода?

Например есть лаунчер, который запускает рабочий клиент, но предварительно проверяет версию приложения и обновляет всё, если версия устарела. Лаунчер может работать из гостевой учётной записи, и если понадобится обновить контент на системном диске и внести записи в реестре, он должен вывести системное окно ввода пароля админа.

Как это делается в Windows?

Comment: Никак =) только запуском "копии" приложения =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, а как делают во всяких установщиках кнопки с фирменным "щитком", намекающим на участие админа в предстоящей операции? Например когда выбираешь "установить для всех пользователей" - во многих инсталлерах такое есть...

Comment: Запускают отдельный процесс, для которого и делается "повышение" прав.
Т.е. нельзя повысить права уже существующего процесса, можно запустить "фоновый" процесс с правами админа, именно это и делается.